# Получить адрес при клике внутри полигона

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api

Создал карту с полигоном на ней http://provlal.ru/. При клике по карте вне полигона вывожу адрес в input (слева), но при клике по полигону, всплывает его балун, а адрес получить не удается, т.е. полигон перекрывает доступ к карте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при клике по полигону не только всплывал балун (он должен всплывать), но и адрес передавался в input.

```
$(function(){
// Функция ymaps.ready() будет вызвана, когда
// загрузятся все компоненты API, а также когда будет готово DOM-дерево.
ymaps.ready(function () {

var myPlacemark;
var map = new ymaps.Map('mymap', {
        center: [51.8, 55.1],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: ['zoomControl']
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();


 // Слушаем клик на карте.
map.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');

    // Если метка уже создана – просто передвигаем ее.
    if (myPlacemark) {
        myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
    }
    // Если нет – создаем.
    else {
        myPlacemark = createPlacemark(coords);
        map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        // Слушаем событие окончания перетаскивания на метке.
        myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
            getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
        });
    }
    getAddress(coords);
});

 function createPlacemark(coords) {
        return new ymaps.Placemark(coords, {
            iconCaption: 'поиск...'
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
            draggable: true
        });
    }


    // Определяем адрес по координатам (обратное геокодирование).
function getAddress(coords) {
    myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
    ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function (res) {
        var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

        myPlacemark.properties
            .set({
                // Формируем строку с данными об объекте.
                iconCaption: [
                    // Название населенного пункта или вышестоящее административно-территориальное образование.
                    firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                    // Получаем путь до топонима, если метод вернул null, запрашиваем наименование здания.
                    firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                // В качестве контента балуна задаем строку с адресом объекта.
                balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
            });
            $('.address-form__field').val(firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());
    });
}

// Загружаем GeoJSON файл, экспортированный из Конструктора карт.
$.getJSON('oren.geojson')
    .done(function (geoJson) {

        geoJson.features.forEach(function (obj) {
            // Задаём контент балуна.
            obj.properties.balloonContent = obj.properties.name;
            // Задаём пресет для меток с полем iconCaption.

        });
        // Добавляем описание объектов в формате JSON в менеджер объектов.
        objectManager.add(geoJson);
        // Добавляем объекты на карту.
        map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ это поменять интерактивность у полигонов:

```
objectManager.options.set('geoObjectInteractivityModel', 'default#transparent');
```

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/#GeoObject__param-options.interactivityModel

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, но заметил еще 1 проблему, при клике по полигону, балун всплывает только 1 раз, т.е. при повторном клике по полигону, балун остается на старом месте, а не всплывает в новой точке. + подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать балун у маркера, на месте клика.

Comment: @балун всплывает только 1 раз@ - это стандартное поведение для геообъекта. Можно подписаться на событие клика по полигону и закрывать предыдущий балун и открывать новый.

Comment: @подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать балун у маркера, на месте клика.@ - не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, соберите минимальный пример на jsfiddle чтобы я понимал что вы хотите сделать.